# Page with Javascript Isn't Being Tracked by Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I've noticed that my music page with other Javascripts on it is not being tracked by Google Analytics. All of my other pages without javascript are being tracked.

Is there something in my script that is preventing Google from tracking this page?

The analytics code for this page is placed adjacent to the `</body>`tag.

I don't think this affects it, but it might. [Page in Question Here if Needed](http://www.caseykidd.com/music.html).

**Update:** I checked my scripts and none are using the _gat and _gaq variables as mentioned below.

**Update 2:** It's just my music page, apparently. So only one page isn't being tracked, and the scripts on that page are listed below.

**Analytics Code:**

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-40498113-1', 'caseykidd.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</body>
```

**Music Page Scripts:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="videobox/js/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="videobox/js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="videobox/js/videobox.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="player/src/jquery.ubaplayer.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
   jQuery.noConflict();
   jQuery(function(){
            jQuery("#ubaPlayer").ubaPlayer({
            codecs: [{name:"MP3", codec: 'audio/mpeg;'}]
            });

    });
    jQuery('a[rel=vidbox]').click(function () {

        if (jQuery("#ubaPlayer").ubaPlayer("playing") === true) {
            jQuery("#ubaPlayer").ubaPlayer("pause");
             }
         return false;
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like the link to your site didn't survive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely reason for GA not triggering is an error in the other js, should be able to see it in chrome console (iPad ATM so can't confirm) - typically "xxx is undefined at line yay of nnnnnn.js"

The JQuery code looks a bit mixed up, copy pasted from several sources...?

```
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(function(){
```

You have a anonymous function inside the doc.ready, setting things more levels deep than needed

And the noConflict should be right after the jQ script line if needed (and it isn't needed as you are not using $ at all, and only doing jQ inside the handler)

Also, I'd try to find either a mootools audio or JQuery video instead of mixing both on same page

**Update**; tested with jsbin, split your page in two, audio and video
Audio tracks fine
But the mootools scripts crashes or overrides Google Analytics, looks like a rather old version as well (2006)

Comment: The easiest solution is probably going to be replacing my Videobox plugin (that uses mootools). Do you think my Analytics will work if I find a jQuery equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

> All of my other pages without javascript are being tracked except two
>   pages with other javascripts.

Based on this statement, I'd suggest you to make sure that all the scripts on your page do not override or use the _gat and _gaq variables which are defined as global variables used by google tracking code.

Comment: Are these the only variables that would possibly be overridden?

Comment: Yes, it is. There should be fine with the tracking code from your own scripts as long as those variables are not used by other scripts on your pages

Comment: I just checked and neither of those are being used.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the `ga()` function is initially created by the analytics snippet, and then redefined by the analytics.js code.

Something in the code on that page is preventing analytics.js from running after it is loaded asynchronously via the analytics code, so `ga()` is stuck with it's initial definition.

You can see this in Chrome via the Developer Tools console window, and looking at `ga` in both the problem page and your home page.

Maybe try moving the analytics code snippet to before the ubaplayer.js code?

Comment: Should I try before it in the `<head>` or place it after `<html>`?

Comment: Normally I'd suggest just before `</head>`, but since there seems to be some kind of conflict, I'd try putting it before the mootools.js script.